# How To Customize External Library Components in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react app and I am using Material UI for the UI. I am also using a Login Component from [@microsoft/mgt-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/mgt-react?activeTab=versions)
On my Home page I am using the Login component from mgt-react to handle login functionalities. The components acccepts props such as loginInitiated, loginCompleted etc that i can pass my functions to. Take a look at the example below

```js
import { Login, Providers } from '@microsoft/mgt-react';

<Login loginInitiated={handleLoginStarted} loginCompleted={handleLoginCompoleted} />
```

Below is how the ui Looks

[image]

The last button called singIn is the @microsoft/mgt-react Login that is imported above.

So my concern is that I do not like the ui of the @microsoft/mgt-react Login component and I want to use the Native Material UI Button components while still having access to the props in the @microsoft/mgt-react Login component such as loginInitiated and loginCompleted.

Is there a way i can forward these props to my own Material UI button Component?

Comment: just target and modify the css. I dont think you can transfer the props because those contain actual functionality of the custom component that you're using

Comment: Review the section on templating here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/tree/c46de5dd59237442f40ee34e55d28248e1428483/packages/mgt-react. You need to pass in a template react component as a child to the Login component. That template component could be a Material Button.